# Why do I have error when I change instapy like_until file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, instapy

I had some problems with liking

> Cannot detect post media type

I read that I should change one line like_until (*span to div*) but when I changed that, I got these error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\SubDesk\Click Bloom\click_bloom_v1.0.0\main.py", line 72, in <module> session.like_by_tags(['bitcoin'], amount=11) File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 1957, in like_by_tags inappropriate, user_name, is_video, reason, scope = check_link( File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\instapy\like_util.py", line 726, in check_link quash = re.search(dont_likes_regex, image_text, re.IGNORECASE) File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 201, in search return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string) File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 304, in _compile p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags) File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags) File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0) File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1, File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_parse.py", line 671, in _parse raise source.error("multiple repeat", re.error: multiple repeat at position 8`

what shoud I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved!
one of my tag contain + and it makes problem

Answer (score 1):

Installing instapy from the command line has this error.

To solve that:

1. Delete any instapy folder in this location:

   ```
   C:\Users[computer-user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages
   ```
2. Go to https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy
3. Download instaPy-master.zip
4. Extract the downloaded file and copy the instapy folder from

   ```
   \InstaPy-master
   ```

   to

   ```
   C:\Users[computer-user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages
   ```
5. Then run your code

Comment: The problem was not about installing instapy.